# Python + Kivy: Dispatching events from backend code

Tags: python, events, kivy

I'm building a smart alarm clock in kivy.  To make it modular, I'm building up each of the main widgets (current time, current weather, alarm, etc) using python code (using layout widgets as base classes) and then positioning those widgets on the screen using the kv language file.

Several of these widgets require weather data, and I have written a class that can fetch this data using the wunderground api.  The problem I have is that api requests are limited, and I don't want to have each widget polling for the same data repeatedly.

My solution would be to build a single class that polls the data on a timer (using the kivy Clock class) and then dispatches an event that "new weather data is availible".  The the widget either reads the data from the event (or better) has a reference to the data backend object so it can request the cached data whenever.

I'm not sure how to approach this in the kivy framework.

Where would this backend class live?  Is it part of the root widget class, or part of the "App" class?

Can the backend object be accessed directly by the widgets?  How is that accomplished?

How do I make these widgets aware of my custom "new_data" event, and how can I tell the widget to listen for it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, the best solution would be to store your weather data in kivy properties.

Kivy properties will automatically update throughout your kivy widgets.

To set up a kivy property, you import the necessary property, and set your varaible to said property:

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

weatherData = StringProperty()
```

You can then reference `weatherData` from your Kivy widgets and they will automatically update.